# How would I go at writing a ajax button in the Yii framework

Tags: javascript, ajax, button, yii, submit

I am currently new to the Yii framework, and I was wondering if anyone had good example or experience with Javascript to assist me creating a ajax submit button. The entire purpose  of this submit button is to favorite the current page and send the data to the / needed.  The label of the button must change depending on the information from the database ( button label -> favorite or un-favorite ).

Here the current functionality from my basic button. I would like to do the next step and start using ajax. If anyone is interested in teaching a newbie. I would be up for the challenge.

```
<div>
    <?php echo CHtml::button('Favorite', array('submit'=>array('user/favoritePage', 'playerId'=>$player->id, 'pageId'=>$page->id, 'bool'=>'FALSE'))); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$toggle = $model->is_favourite? "false": "true";

$actionUrl = Yii::app()->createUrl('user/favoritePage', array(
    'playerId'=>$player->id, 'pageId'=>$page->id
));


//render input type=submit with id=favourite-button
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
    ($model->is_favourite? 'Favourite' : 'Un-Favourite'), //label button
    $actionUrl,
    array(
        'data' => 'js:{bool: $("#favourite-button").attr("toggle")}', //get current status of button (favourite or not) as param to post
        'success'=>'js:function(data){
//ajax success, update label and status of button for next time
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        $("#favourite-button").val(data["label"]);
        $("#favourite-button").attr("toggle", data["toggle"]);
        }'

    ),
    array(
        'id'        => 'favourite-button', // set id for button
        'toggle'    => $toggle // set attribute to hold favourite status, or you can set it on hidden field instead and then update the selector on ajax success 
    )
);
```

On controller User

```
public function actionfavoritePage(){
if( Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest(){ // this check is not necessary if you write this function just for ajax call only

$playerId- = $_GET['playerId']; // get query string
$pageId- = $_GET['pageId']; // get query string
$bool = $_POST['bool']; // get status true OR false 

//do your stuff to save status here
...


//then return result as json
echo json_encode(array('label' => '[your new button label]', 'toggle'=>$bool?'false':'true'));

exit();
})


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `CHtml::ajaxButton()`:  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxButton-detail

Here's a tutorial on how to use it: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/49/update-content-in-ajax-with-renderpartial/

If you want the title of your button to change, place a condition in a view, and make sure your button is returned in the ajax result.